# Regex: Get a list of id

Tags: c#, regex

I need to get a list of id from a string. The regex for the string is like this:

```
"GET_LIST( [A-Za-z0-9]{5,10}){0,100}";
```

When I send a string like this:

```
GET_LIST 1000 10001 10002
```

I'd like to get something like `"10000 10001 10002"` or better a list of id. But when I try to get this with `matches.Groups[1].Value;`
I only get the last id.

My code look like this actually :

```
public IList<string> ExctractListId(string command)
{
    IList<string> id = new List<string>();
    Match matches = new Regex(ReponseListeService).Match(command);
    if (matches.Success)
    {

        string ids = matches.Groups[1].Value;
        Console.WriteLine(ids);
        return id;
    }

    return id;
}
```

I know that the code is not fully right, actually I just want get a list or a string with all the id

This code is for a homework and I can't use, Split(), Concat(), ...

How can I have this ?

Comment: Your example doesn't match your question. Perhaps show us what you have tried so we can show you where it is breaking.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just do `var ids = str.Split(' ').Skip(1).ToList();`?

Comment: I would always use `string.Split()` for easy things like this, @itsme86 has the right approach

Comment: If you really need to only get the results from a string in this exact format, use https://ideone.com/cJhJdL

Comment: I can't use string.Split() beacause it's for a homework and the teacher not allow us to us it. 

I've update the post with the actual code

Comment: See [this demo](https://ideone.com/Ey8uCi).

Comment: Thank you for your help @Wiktor Stribiżew, it work perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
private static string pattern = @"^GET_LIST(?:\s+([A-Za-z0-9]{4,10})){0,100}$";
private static List<string> ExtractListId(string command)
{
    return Regex.Matches(command, pattern)
        .Cast<Match>().SelectMany(p => p.Groups[1].Captures
            .Cast<Capture>()
            .Select(t => t.Value)
        )
        .ToList();
}
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/Ey8uCi) and a [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5EGET_LIST%28%3F%3A%5Cs%2B%28%5BA-Za-z0-9%5D%7B4%2C10%7D%29%29%7B0%2C100%7D%24&i=GET_LIST%201000%2010001%2010002). Results:

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - matches start of string
- `GET_LIST` - a literal substring
- `(?:\s+([A-Za-z0-9]{4,10})){0,100}` - 0 to 100 occurrences of

  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `([A-Za-z0-9]{4,10})` - Capturing group 1: 4 to 10 alphanumeric ASCII chars
- `$` - end of string.

Note that we have a capturing group (`([A-Za-z0-9]{4,10})`) inside a quantified non-capturing group `(?:...){0,100}`. To get those values, you should access the group capture collection. As the group has ID 1, you need to get `match.Groups[1]` and access all its `.Captures`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `String.Split()` method to split the string on whitespace characters, and then return all items that can be parsed to an `int`. Note that this will return **all** items that are valid integers, so it will work with your sample input, but if you have other types of input it may need some modification.

```
public static IList<string> ExctractListId(string command)
{
    if (command == null || !command.StartsWith("GET_LIST"))
    {
        return new List<string>();
    }

    int temp;
    return command.Split().Where(item => int.TryParse(item, out temp)).ToList();
}
```

Example usage:

```
private static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", ExctractListIds("GET_LIST 1000 10001 10002")));

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The data your are searching contains white-space. So in the regex add `white-space` or `\s` and try again.

Hope this helps.

Sorry, I counldn't completely understand the problem.

A small code snippet using Javascript

```
function getId(data){

    var regex = /^GET_LIST(([\d\s]{5,10}){0,100})/g;

    var match = regex.exec(data);
    console.log(match[1]);  
}
```

Comment: Its great to participate in the community, but you should only post an answer when you have a definitive answer.  This is more of a comment and unfortunately you do not have the rep to post a comment yet.  Try answering some questions you can answer fully, or asking questions to build rep

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion maccettura. I will keep it in mind, I just wanted to help.